# C++ new gdiplus::bitmap in DLL return null

Tags: c++, object, bitmap, gdi+

I was using the GDI object in DLL but `new gdiplus::bitmap` in DLL returned `NULL`. Other new objects succeed. I used `GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, gdiplusStartupInput, NULL)` to initialize.

The code:

```
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
...
Gdiplus::Bitmap *bmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(bmp_info.bmWidth, bmp_info.bmHeight, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
```

Is there any GDI initialization work or other initialization that's missed or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I initialized in the DLLMain entry at the beginning. Now I changed the initialization to the function using the GDI Object.